# How to use "with execute as" while querying a linked server from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, linked-server

I have a strange permission issue with SQL Server 2019 (same thing happened also with 2016 version).

I have a database ReportDB, where **reportuser** (login: reportlogin) can run several reports.

I also have a linked server Linked5 where **linkeduser** (login: linkedlogin) has login mapping for a 3rd party application. Other users cannot use this linked server.

Now I need to create a report that accesses the linked server and give reportuser permissions to run this procedure. But reportuser can't have more permissions to this linked server.

I did this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_linked_server_test]
with execute as 'linkeduser'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    select *
    from openquery(Linked5, 'select * from table;')
END
GRANT EXECUTE TO _linked_server_test to reportuser
```

This works, if procedure has been run previously by linkeduser. But if plan cache is emptied (reboot, dbcc freeproccache) I get the following error.

> [Error] Script lines: 5-5 -------------------------- Id 7416, Level
> 16, State 1, Line 7 Access to the remote server is denied because no
> login-mapping exists. Msg: 7416, Level: 16, State: 1, Procedure:
> _linked_server_test, Line: 7

Running procedure once as linkeduser gets a new plan and procedure works again with reportuser permissions.

If I create a login mapping for reportuser, procedure works without "execute as", but as said I can't do this.

How to do this properly? Get rid of plan requirement and create a procedure that queries linked server without login mapping for reportuser?

EDIT:
I tried granting SHOWPLAN to reportuser, it didn't help. (Thank you for the suggestion)

EDIT2:
If I change the openquery to dynamic sql I can get this to work with "execute as". This becomes convoluted really fast.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[_linked_server_test]
with execute as 'linkeduser'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    declare @sqlstr nvarchar(1000) = 'select * from openquery(Linked5, ''select * from table;'')'
    exec(@sqlstr)
END
```

EDIT3:
If I give impersonate permission to reportuser, I can do this and switch to linkeduser outside the procedure, without going to dynamic sql. I wonder what is the difference here vs having "with execute as" inside the procedure.

```
grant impersonate on user::linkeduser to reportuser
GO
execute as user = 'linkeduser';
exec _linked_server_test
```

Comment: Can you grant SHOWPLAN to reportuser?

https://moredvikas.wordpress.com/2016/05/12/how-to-grant-show-plan-permission-in-sql-server/